# MediaCodec: native_window_api_connect returned an error: No such device (-19)

Tags: android, h.264, android-mediacodec

when I use MediaCodec,got a crash.
the stack trace:

> I/ VideoHW/VideoDecoder: createVideoDecoder
>       I/ACodec:  [] Now uninitialized
>       I/ACodec: [] onAllocateComponent
>       I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
>       I/ACodec: Set Google AAC Dec for aacProfile 0
>       I/ACodec: [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] Now Loaded
>       E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-11590-3] conn
>       E/MediaCodec: native_window_api_connect returned an er
>       E/MediaCodec: configure failed with err 0xffffffed, re
>       I/ACodec:  [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] Now uninitiali
>       I/ACodec:  [] Now kWhatShutdownCompleted event : 8362
>       I/MediaCodec: Codec shutdown complete
>       I/ACodec:  [] Now uninitialized
>       I/ACodec: [] onAllocateComponent
>       I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
>       I/ACodec: Set Google AAC Dec for aacProfile 0
>       W/Activity: AppLock checkAppLockState locked:false ver
>       alse
>       D/SVPlayerView: onSurfaceTextureAvailable width 1080 h
>       I/KugouPlayer/JNI: ++++++end call 
>       I/ACodec: [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] Now Loaded
>       D/siganid: is crash
>       D/siganid: isForeProcess:true
>       android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0xffffffed                                                                         >     at android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(Native Method)
>       at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:1882)

```
public boolean createVideoDecoder(Object surface,int width, int height, byte[] sps, byte[] pps) {
        Log.i(TAG,"createVideoDecoder");
        mFormat = new MediaFormat();
        mFormat.setString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME, "video/avc");
        mFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_WIDTH, width);
        mFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_HEIGHT, height);
        byte[] head = { 0, 0, 0, 1 };
        ByteBuffer bSPS = ByteBuffer.allocate(sps.length + head.length);
        ByteBuffer bPPS = ByteBuffer.allocate(pps.length + head.length);
        bSPS.put(head);
        bSPS.put(sps);
        bSPS.flip();
        bPPS.put(head);
        bPPS.put(pps);
        bPPS.flip();
        mFormat.setByteBuffer("csd-0", bSPS);
        mFormat.setByteBuffer("csd-1", bPPS);

        mFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
        try {
            mCodec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/avc");
            if (mCodec == null) {
                return false;
            }
            mCodec.configure(mFormat, (Surface) surface, null, 0);
            mCodec.start();
            info = new BufferInfo();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```